# What is the proper way to harvest Chamomile flowers?

Tags: harvesting, flowering

I have some Chamomile plants that have started to flower and I would like to use them to for tea, but I am unsure of how.

**1. When should I pick the flowers?**

**2. Do they need to be dried to be used?**

Below is a picture of their current state.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=harvesting%20chamomile%20flowers&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=http://www.gardenguides.com/526-chamomile-culinary-herbs-short-season-gardeners.html&ei=OKx5T9b8CKH00gHftJS6DQ&usg=AFQjCNGNXgHXpm5MxHuNLYhkMaPuai9brg), Chamomile should be harvested as soon as they are fully open. delaying it will reduce the flavor. The plants in your picture have plenty of good flowers that need to be picked. They can be used fresh or dried. Put the flowers on a screen in a warm airy room with low humidity. Circulating the air with an electric fan helps the drying process.